# CSS: fixed div next to relative div

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a fixed div adjacent to a scrolling div, such as [Fixed div next to a centered div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647996/fixed-div-next-to-a-centered-div) asks.  I've looked at that one and [Fixed div next to parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430320/fixed-div-next-to-parent-div), but it doesn't seem to work on what I'm doing.  Here's the code for what I'm working on (without any code for what I'm trying to make):  http://jsfiddle.net/Firedrake969/dbLt9/

I've tried

```
float:left;
```

but it doesn't work with

```
position:fixed;
```

Also, on a tangent, the background div, as it is fixed, does not let you scroll the page.

Comment: Nothing is scrollable in your demo.

Comment: That's part of the problem...

Comment: Remove position: fixed; on #back. Then it should work.

Comment: Doing that gives white space when I scroll:  http://prntscr.com/49zewa

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed position div scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894400/fixed-position-div-scrollable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/dbLt9/7/)** here
^ Above is the updated link of your code.

**Discuss:**

You don't need to define `height` and `position` in `#back` div. Just remove them from CSS. You may see an automated margin added by the browser itself. To override this set `margin: 0;` to the `body`.

Also on your `#intro` div you are using `top: 20px;` which makes this div overflowing it's parent. Instead you can just use `margin-top: 20px;`

Comment: Thank you!  What about making the Menu div stay next to the center column?  Another example would be something like this:  http://barungbiru.neocities.org/  (try resizing it)

Comment: It still leaves white space, but in a different area:  firedrake969.github.io

Comment: I'm not seeing any white-space on your website.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it.  Any ideas about my first problem?  (Keeping the menu div next to the centered column)

Comment: Set a width on the `#back` div and float `#intro` to the right. Currently you are hiding the menu using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/dbLt9/56/)

or, maybe you wanted this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/dbLt9/57/)

```css
#top {
    text-align:center;
    background: aliceblue;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    height: 30px;
}
#menu {
    background-color:#8F8E94;        
    font-size:35px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='top'>Welcome!</div>
<div id='menu'>
Menu <br>
Lorem ipsum dolos accusata pericula. Nonumy saperet alienum per ne, an nam mutat autem, vel diam evertitur sadipscing eu. Errem graece cotidieque an pri. Per et idque populo luptatum.
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolos accusata pericula. Nonumy saperet alienum per ne, an nam mutat autem, vel diam evertitur sadipscing eu. Errem graece cotidieque an pri. Per et idque populo luptatum.
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolos accusata pericula. Nonumy saperet alienum per ne, an nam mutat autem, vel diam evertitur sadipscing eu. Errem graece cotidieque an pri. Per et idque populo luptatum.
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolos accusata pericula. Nonumy saperet alienum per ne, an nam mutat autem, vel diam evertitur sadipscing eu. Errem graece cotidieque an pri. Per et idque populo luptatum.

</div>
```